# AVPlayer in UITableViewCell results in "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" error

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I am trying to setup a custom UITableViewCell that will include a video player in the cell.

I am getting a `"Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"` on the line:

`"playerLayer.frame = self.videoPlayerSuperView.bounds"`

Here is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class feedCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewsLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerSuperView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let videoURL = URL(string: "https://some.url.of.an.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.videoPlayerSuperView.bounds
        self.videoPlayerSuperView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Your `videoPlayerSuperView` is not `ready` in `awakeFromNib`. After the cell is created, you can use it. e.g. create a separate method for setting the frame. and call that method after you create the cell in cellForRow.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem, sorted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AjinkyaSharma

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let videoURL = URL(string: "https://some.url.of.an.mp4")
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.videoPlayerSuperView.bounds
        self.videoPlayerSuperView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try By Adding Delay

```
override func awakeFromNib() 
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.2 , 
   execute:
    {
         let videoURL = URL(string: "https://some.url.of.an.mp4")
         let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
         let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
         playerLayer.frame = self.videoPlayerSuperView.bounds
         self.videoPlayerSuperView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
         player.play()

    })

}
```